# Failure to make Foreign keys with two tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am in the process of building the website for the Linq, and the way that I need is to use Foreign keys to precisely set the same with my users table.¨

I have assured me that my Tabler has a primary key because it must be unique content that use grab.

**Its a brugere table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[brugere] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username]    NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [password]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_brugere] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_brugere_ToPoint] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [pointantal]([brugerid]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_brugere_ToKunde] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [KundeData]([brugerid])
);
```

**Poinantal its here**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pointantal] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [point]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [omrade]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [datotid]  DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [brugerid] INT            NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_pointantal] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
```

**and KundeData table here**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KundeData] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Adresse]       NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [Postnr]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [Mobil]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [Byen]          NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [abonnementsId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [BuyDate]       DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [prisid]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [HaevedeId]     NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [brugerid]      INT            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The error message I receive when I try to updater content is here

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.
>   Please correct the following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[pointantal]' contains no
>   primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in
>   the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it
>   should be persisted. SQL71516 :: The referenced table
>   '[dbo].[KundeData]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match
>   the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced
>   column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Comment: You can *only* reference the **primary key** or a column with a **unique index** on it in another table - neither of these things is the case for your two tables here.....

Comment: Both your foreign keys are referencing the `brugerid` column in those tables - but that's **not** the primary key column for those tables, nor do they seem to be unique columns - therefore, you *cannot* reference these with a foreign key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foreign key can only reference a primary key or unique column. You can either add a unique constraint to the columns that you are referencing:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pointantal] (
    ...
    CONSTRAINT AK_BrugerID UNIQUE(brugerid)
```

Or you can change your constraint to actually reference the primary key in your tables:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_brugere_ToPoint] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [pointantal]([Id])
```

However, it seems like you really want the `brugerid` column of the `pointantal` and `KundeData` tables to access an `Id` (which is a unique column) in the `brugere` table. In this case, you put the foreign  key on those tables and have it access the primary key of the `bruger` table. The following code runs sucessfully on my system:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[brugere] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username]    NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [password]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_brugere] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pointantal] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [point]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [omrade]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [datotid]  DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [brugerid] INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_pointantal] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_point_ToBrugere] FOREIGN KEY ([brugerid]) REFERENCES [brugere]([Id])
);
```

Comment: The two tables *do have* a primary key (`id`), but the foreign keys are not referencing that column, but `brugerid` instead (which is *not* the PK nor a unique column)

Comment: Good catch. I wonder what he actually wants. brugerid seems like it wouldn't be unique in KundeData

Comment: @MillieSmith It will still be in error, which means that it will not do so at all. It should in no way set it together. But Shall I go up in my example and show what I do ?, as it comes with a new error,.

Comment: @JesperPetersen Just post the error as a comment here.

Comment: @MillieSmith its error are : **Incorrect syntax near CONSTRAINT**

Comment: Which constraint did you try to add? Can you pastebin.com your new code and post the pastebin link as a comment here? @JesperPetersen

Comment: It is such that I must not get hold of ID but userid when users id be careful with the same userid, as I said, the user may have more information to the table so he can have more adganger to the table.

You can see its here: http://pastebin.com/J8iafear @MillieSmith

Comment: @JesperPetersen Why are you adding the foreign keys to the brugere table? You should be adding the foreign keys to the pointantal and KundeData tables.

Comment: @MillieSmith Unfortunately I can not quite see what you mean by what you say,

Comment: @MillieSmith So what I'm doing wrong the wrong way. and I give you the thumps up to help me with this problem and you must have a good evening

Answer (score 0):

> a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that
>   uniquely identifies a row of another table. In simpler words, the
>   foreign key is defined in a second table, but it refers to the primary
>   key in the first table.

Try:

**1>Change the Reference column**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pointantal] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [point]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [omrade]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [datotid]  DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [brugerid] INT            NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_pointantal] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KundeData] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Adresse]       NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [Postnr]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [Mobil]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [Byen]          NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [abonnementsId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [BuyDate]       DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [prisid]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [HaevedeId]     NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [brugerid]      INT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[brugere] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username]    NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [password]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_brugere] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_brugere_ToPoint] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [pointantal]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_brugere_ToKunde] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [KundeData]([Id])
);
```

**2>Change The Primary-Key**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pointantal] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [point]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [omrade]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [datotid]  DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [brugerid] INT            NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_pointantal] PRIMARY KEY ([brugerid])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KundeData] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Adresse]       NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [Postnr]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [Mobil]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [Byen]          NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [abonnementsId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [BuyDate]       DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [prisid]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [HaevedeId]     NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [brugerid]      INT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([brugerid])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[brugere] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username]    NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [password]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_brugere] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_brugere_ToPoint] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [pointantal]([brugerid]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_brugere_ToKunde] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [KundeData]([brugerid])
);
```